Why don't these resistors affect the gain in voltage divider bias?
Our textbook says that voltage gain is not affected by the R1 and R2 resistors, but I don't understand the reason behind it.
Also, don't we get the 1/gm that is in the denominator from r(pi) resistor on the base and if we are considering that resistor for the gain, shouldn't we also consider the R1&2 resistors?
Also, I saw a couple of questions which consider the resistors which are in series with r(pi). From what I'm getting they affect the gain because they are in series with r(pi) but R1 and R2 in this case don't, because they are in parallel, is that the reason behind it?

Source:Fundamentals of Microelectronics,Razavi

nwnd - Hi, Where did that image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each item. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) please [edit] the question & add its name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the original source is a printed book or other offline material, please [edit] the question & add the best reference you can e.g. title, author(s), page, edition etc. (see the linked rule for details). TY

The gain is Vout/Vin.  In the small-signal sense, R1 & R2 are in parallel with each other and an ideal voltage source.  Since the voltage source has zero output impedance, nothing in parallel with it can affect its value.
In the practical case where the source has a finite output impedance, the parallel combination of R1 and R2 will act as the lower leg of a voltage divider (along with the impedance seen looking into the base). The source impedance will be the upper leg, and therefore will affect the gain.

Thank you for your answer.I couldn't understand what you mean by "since the voltage source has zero output impedance".Are you suggesting that the Vin is grounded so the resistors in parallel to that are short-circuited?Also for example,while we are finding Rin,we add a Vx source,does this count as practical case?

@nwnd For an ideal voltage source, you can add an arbitrary resistance in parallel and the voltage is unaffected.  For example in circuit "b" R1 could be 1 microohm and Vin wouldn't change.
